# Incorrect suggested edit review count

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

When I was going through my suggested edit history, I found the following stat oddity:

[image]

As you can see, I have 1,707 suggested edits in total (which is correct), but according to my reviewer stats, I only have 933!

---

The odder thing is that when I look at a review audit, that number shows up correctly!

[image]

What's going on?

---

**EDIT**: This appears to not be a client-caching issue; this is the response from the server for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7175628) suggested edit (the field of interest being "moreInstructions":

```
{
    "isUnavailable":true,
    "instructions":"<div class=\"review-status\">\r\n                    <strong>\r\n<span style=\"color: #0A0;\">Approved</span> <span title=\"2015-02-27 00:28:45Z\" class=\"relativetime\">15 hours ago</span>:                    </strong>\r\n    </div>    \r\n        <div class=\"review-results\">\r\n            <a href=\"/users/899126/chrisforrence\" class=\"comment-user\">ChrisForrence</a> reviewed this <span title=\"2015-02-27 00:28:45Z\" class=\"relativetime\">15 hours ago</span>: <b>Approve</b>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class=\"review-results\">\r\n            <a href=\"/users/%c4%99g\" class=\"comment-user\"> &#39;&#39;</a> reviewed this <span title=\"2015-02-27 00:23:25Z\" class=\"relativetime\">15 hours ago</span>: <b>Reject</b>\r\n        </div>\r\n                    <div class=\"rejection-reason cool\">This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.</div>\r\n        <div class=\"review-results\">\r\n            <a href=\"/users/609087/keety\" class=\"comment-user\">keety</a> reviewed this <span title=\"2015-02-27 00:15:52Z\" class=\"relativetime\">15 hours ago</span>: <b>Approve</b>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class=\"review-results\">\r\n            <a href=\"/users/1907093/jonathan-crowe\" class=\"comment-user\">Jonathan Crowe</a> reviewed this <span title=\"2015-02-27 00:05:09Z\" class=\"relativetime\">15 hours ago</span>: <b>Approve</b>\r\n        </div>",
    "moreInstructions":"<p><strong>Reviewer Stats</strong></p>\r\n    <ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/users/899126/chrisforrence\">ChrisForrence</a> has approved 960 edit suggestions and rejected 5 edit suggestions</li>\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/users/%c4%99g\"> &#39;&#39;</a> has approved 7 edit suggestions and rejected 28 edit suggestions</li>\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/users/609087/keety\">keety</a> has approved 126 edit suggestions and rejected 14 edit suggestions</li>\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/users/1907093/jonathan-crowe\">Jonathan Crowe</a> has approved 79 edit suggestions and rejected 6 edit suggestions</li>\r\n    </ul>\r\n        <p><strong>Editor Stats</strong></p>\r\n        <ul>\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/users/4476153/fizz-binn\">Fizz Binn</a> had 2 edit suggestions approved, and 0 edit suggestions rejected</li>\r\n        </ul>",
    "actions":[
        {
            "type":254,
            "name":"Next",
            "description":"review next item",
            "tooltip":"review next item",
            "disabled":false
        }
    ],
    "reviewTaskId":7175628,
    "content":"<snip>",
    "actionDelay":0,
    "badgeProgress":"1,764",
    "suggestedEditCount":0
}
```

As you can see, the server is saying that I've only rejecting 5 edit suggestions, even though it's been established earlier that I have far more than that count.

Comment: Do you choose "improve edit" or "reject and edit" often?

Comment: The majority of my reviews were before those options were available, but I'll do it on occasion. I should have roughly 800 edit rejections

Comment: The thing is, those options don't count neither to "approved ... " nor "rejected ... " but increments your counter.

Comment: @nicael - That's not quite what I was getting at; I've clicked "Reject" on roughly 600 suggested edits, so that 1 should be 605. I found another interesting screenshot from a review audit that _does_ show the proper reject count, so I'll be editing my post with that.

Comment: Related on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272597/suggested-edits-showing-the-wrong-stats

Comment: I have a query [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/257610?UserId=1043380) to support the weirdness

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in build 3746 for MSE/MSO, and build 2869 for other sites.

Many thanks to Jon Ericson for diagnosing the issue!

Answer (score 15):

The same query is used for both displays. It's been a while since you asked the question, so current data doesn't match:

```
Review Result   Total 
--------------- ----- 
Approve           997   
Edit              193   
Not Sure          936   
Reject            649   
Reject and Edit    10
```

A more recent example is Seth's Ask Ubuntu review stats. According to [an audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/475662):

[image: Seth's suggested edit review stats (audit)]

Meanwhile, according to a [regular review](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/475626):

[image: Seth's suggested edit review stats (buggy)]

```
Review Result   Total 
--------------- ----- 
Approve          3023  
Edit              623   
Not Sure           68    
Reject            728   
Reject and Edit     9
```

Therefore, the audit result page is using just the "Reject" review result reason, while the regular result page is using just the "Reject and Edit" reason. Arguably, both displays are wrong. They should sum up both the rejections reasons.

I'll check with a developer to see if we can fix this bug.

Comment: @ChrisForrence I've now implemented adding the "Edit" count to the "Approve" count, to mirror the "RejectAndEdit" count being added to the "Reject" count, on our internal dev system, so there's a proof of concept. (I'm waiting to hear back from Jon Ericson about whether it's desired; if so, it will appear in "meta" build 3747 and "prod" build 2870. If not, it will be rolled back. :-P)

Comment: @ChrisForrence After more discussions with another community manager, we felt it would be better to split improved edits into a third category (reject-and-edits are still counted as rejected). So that's what I've implemented now.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Builds 3747/2870 have been deployed a few minutes ago, so you should see the newly-added third category in the reviewer stats. Enjoy!