# Improved X edit suggestions

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, improve-edit

I noticed today that the reviewer stats on suggested edits now says something like

> user31415 has approved X edit suggestions and rejected Y edit suggestions and improved Z edit suggestions

I'm pretty sure I don't remember seeing the "improved X edit suggestions" part of that before today. Is this a new feature? And is their a reason why we don't get any stats on "reject and edit" amounts?

Comment: Looks like the result of [this bug fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243910/incorrect-suggested-edit-review-count) (fixed four days ago). As for "reject and edit" guess it's included in the "improved".